# can we have the sql without loop?

Tags: sql

can we have a query to have the following output..? is that possible with sql?

We have a table with row numbers such as from 1 to 15 (sequence)

and we have another table which holds from and to row number such as
[table2 - control table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGDmb.png)

and based on the 2nd table we need to join first table and get the output as below:
[table3 -output table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxpWE.png)

so can we have such type of output from SQL without using loops?

thanks,
Girish

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a between comparison like this:

```
select Id, FROM_ROW from table2, table1
where table1.kId between table2.FROM_ROW and table2.TO_ROW -1
```

You will need an additional row in table2 for row 15.

Answer (score 1):

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> SELECT * FROM T;
+----------+--------+
| from_row | to_row |
+----------+--------+
|        1 |      4 |
|        4 |      6 |
|        6 |      9 |
|        9 |     13 |
+----------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> SELECT * FROM USERS;
+-----+----------+--------------+--------+---------------------+
| id  | userName | photo        | status | ts                  |
+-----+----------+--------------+--------+---------------------+
|   1 | John     | john.png     |      1 | 2016-12-08 13:14:24 |
|   2 | Jane     | jane.png     |      1 | 2016-12-08 13:14:24 |
|   3 | Ali      |              |      1 | 2016-12-08 13:14:24 |
|   6 | Bruce    | bruce.png    |      1 | 2016-12-08 13:14:24 |
|   7 | Martha   |              |      1 | 2016-12-08 13:14:24 |
|   8 | Sidney   |              |      1 | 2016-12-08 13:14:24 |
|  10 | Charlie  | charlie.png  |      1 | 2016-12-08 13:14:24 |
|  12 | Elisa    |              |      1 | 2016-12-08 13:14:24 |
|  14 | Samantha | samantha.png |      1 | 2016-12-08 13:14:24 |
|  15 | Hannah   | hannah.png   |      1 | 2016-12-08 13:14:24 |
|  16 | Hannah   |              |      1 | 2016-12-08 13:14:24 |
|  17 | Kevin    | kevin1.png   |      1 | 2016-12-08 13:14:24 |
|  18 | Kevin    | kevin2.png   |      1 | 2016-12-08 13:14:24 |
|  19 | Ruth     |              |      1 | 2016-12-08 13:14:24 |
| 999 | xxx      | photo        |      1 | 2016-12-08 13:16:41 |
+-----+----------+--------------+--------+---------------------+
15 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> SELECT U.ID, FROM_row as start_row
    -> FROM USERS U
    -> JOIN T ON U.ID
    -> BETWEEN T.FROM_row AND T.TO_row
    -> ;
+----+-----------+
| ID | start_row |
+----+-----------+
|  1 |         1 |
|  2 |         1 |
|  3 |         1 |
|  6 |         4 |
|  6 |         6 |
|  7 |         6 |
|  8 |         6 |
| 10 |         9 |
| 12 |         9 |
+----+-----------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```